# Show all variations of a component on a single page in React Storybook but still have Knobs?

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I have a button component that can be of different types eg `primary`, `secondary`, etc:

```
export const buttonTypes = [
  'primary',
  'secondary',
  'tertiary',
  'positive',
  'negative',
]

const Button = ({ text, type }) => {
    return(
        <button className={type}>{text}</button>
    )
}

Button.propTypes = {
    text: PropTypes.string,
    type: PropTypes.oneOf(buttonTypes),
}
```

In my Storybook file I'm mapping through the options. This means you can see all the variants on a single page and if another string was added to the `buttonTypes` array it would automatically be added to the style guide:

```
import ButtonComponent, { buttonTypes } from './Button';

const Button = () => {
    return(
        <div>
            {
                buttonTypes.map(type=>(
                    <ButtonComponent key={type} text={type} type={type} />
                ))
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default {
  title: 'Components',
  component: Button,
};
```

The problem is that this doens't work with with many of the add-ons eg knobs. For knobs to work you need `Button` to be the actual component, not a wrapper as I did above.

```
import ButtonComponent, { buttonTypes } from './Button';

const Button = () => {
  return (
    <ButtonComponent
      type={select('type', buttonTypes, buttonTypes.primary)}
      text="Button"
    />
  );
};
```

Is there a way to use knobs and show all the variations on a single page? Ideally without having to create each component manually as this is more work and then won't automatically update if a new string is added to `buttonTypes`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [grouping](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/tree/master/addons/knobs#categorization) feature of knobs, that way each instance of your component will get its own knob instance instead of all the knob instances being shared between all of the component instances.  You can even mix grouped knobs with non-grouped nobs if you want certain things to be shared and other not to be.

In the following example, I have a `<Button/>` story where each instance has its own copy of the `type` and `disabled` properties, but the `text` is shared between them all.

Each button type gets its own panel where you can set its `type` and `disabled`.  The "Other" group contains any knobs that didn't have their group set (such as `text`).

[image: Button StoryBook Example]

**src/Button/Button.component.jsx**

```
import * as React from "react";

import "./Button.style.css";

export const Button = ({
    text,
    type,
    disabled,
    onClick
}) => (
    <button
        className={`button button--${type} ${disabled ? "button--disabled" : ""}`}
        disabled={disabled}
        onClick={onClick}
        children={text}
    />
);
```

**src/Button/Button.stories.jsx**

```
import * as React from "react";
import {withKnobs, text, boolean, select} from "@storybook/addon-knobs";
import {action} from "@storybook/addon-actions";

import {Button, buttonTypes} from "./";

export default {
    title: "Button",
    component: Button,
    decorators: [withKnobs]
};

export const ButtonStory = () => {
    const buttontext = text("Text", "Click Me");

    return (
        <div>
            {buttonTypes.map(buttonType => (
                <div key={buttonType}>
                    <Button
                        type={select("Type", buttonTypes, buttonType, buttonType)}
                        disabled={boolean("Disabled", false, buttonType)}
                        onClick={action(`${buttonType} clicked`)}
                        text={buttontext}
                    />
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};

ButtonStory.story = {
    name: "All"
}
```

**src/Button/Button.types.js**

```js
export const buttonTypes = [
    "primary",
    "secondary",
    "tertiary"
];
```

**src/Button/Button.style.css**

```css
.button {
    padding: 0.5em;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
}

.button--primary {
    background-color: rgb(132, 198, 106);
    color: black;
    border-color: black;
}

.button--secondary {
    background-color: rgb(194, 194, 194);
    color: black;
    border-color: black;
}

.button--tertiary {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: inherit;
    border-color: transparent;
}

.button--disabled {
    background-color: rgb(194, 194, 194);
    color: rgb(105, 102, 102);
    border-color: rgb(105, 102, 102);
}
```

**src/Button/index.js**

```js
export {Button} from "./Button.component";
export {buttonTypes} from "./Button.types";
```