# Display Multiple Variants in Storybook Without Multiple Stories?

Tags: storybook

I am building a Storybook and would like to display multiple variants of the same component in the 'Docs' tab, without creating new stories under the component in the left nav. Is this possible?

For example, I have the following component:

```js
export const Template = (args) => (
  <Alert {...args}></Alert>
)

<Canvas>
  <Story
    name="Filled Alert"
    args={{
      children: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
      severity: 'info',
      variant: 'filled'
    }}>
    {Template.bind({})}
  </Story>
</Canvas>
```

This component has multiple `severity` values that I would like to show ('info', 'success', 'warning', 'error'). If I create another `<Story>` to show that variant in the documentation:

```js
<Story
  name="Filled Alert - Success"
  args={{
    children: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
    severity: 'success',
    variant: 'filled'
  }}>
  {Template.bind({})}
</Story>
```

In this case, I'll get two entries under 'Alert' for each of the stories above. What I'd like though is only a single 'Filled Alert' entry. The `Canvas` showing a single component that can be played with and the `Docs` showing my MDX documentation.

But (to make it more tricky), I am trying to get a unique entry for each `variant` property. So:

- Alert

  - Filled Alert
  - Standard Alert
  - Outline Alert

Each of the sub-bullets showing different `severity`, but not creating new children.

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried using @addon-knobs as referenced on this [SO post?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61931185/show-all-variations-of-a-component-on-a-single-page-in-react-storybook-but-still)

The [@addon-knobs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@storybook/addon-knobs) has been deprecated in favor of [@addon-controls](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/essentials/controls).